# Should we add an article in the phrase "by return owl" in this case?

Tags: articles

> what do you think you are playing at, walking off into the forest with Viktor Krum? I want you to swear, **by return owl**, that you are not going to go walking with anyone else at night. There is somebody highly dangerous at Hogwarts.

I'm wondering if we should add an article in "*by return owl*", like "*by **a** return owl*". Why does it not take any articles here? How should we understand it?

Excerpted from Harry Potter

Comment: "How are you getting to work?" "By car."

Comment: @JasonBassford, Can it be "By red car"?

Comment: It would be extremely unusual to hear that.

Comment: @JasonBassford, ok, that's why I feel "by return owl" is odd. It's good to me if it put "by owl".

Comment: Well, maybe. *By return owl* is quite different than *by red car*. In the latter, *red* is incidental. It doesn't matter what colour the car is in terms of it being able to get you to your destination. In the former, however, *return* serves an actual function. In the real world, we can say *send the mail by post* or we can say *send the mail by* ***priority*** *post*. In the magic world, *by* ***return*** *owl* could be significant.

Comment: @JasonBassford, they don't actually define "return owl" as a special term in the book. In contrast, it's just like "return post" in the real world in my opinion. Is "send it by return post" correct in the real world?

Comment: Yes. Although, generally, you wouldn't say that you would send it by return post. The original sender would say that they'd provided a postage-paid return envelope. But the idea's the same. (The person replying wouldn't be misunderstood if they said they were sending it by return mail—or post.)

Comment: If I remember correctly, this excerpt is from a letter to Harry by Sirius. Maybe Sirius is just referring to the fact that Harry should send the response by the same owl that got him the letter in the first place, but then the definite article "the" makes more sense.

Comment: @CinCout yes, It's that letter.

Comment: "Return post" did exist.  At one time it was common for the postman to collect post at the same time as receiving it.  In London there were five or six deliveries a day, and it would be reasonable for the wealthy to receive a postcard, ask the postman to wait, write respond to it, hand the response back to the postie for delivery the same day.  This was called replying "by return post"

Comment: The expression I'm familiar with is _by return of post_, meaning that you put the answer in the mail as soon as possible so that it will be taken with the next collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here "owl" is being used in a rather unusual way.  It is the uncountable *method* of delivering a letter.

When a word is used to give a method, it is used uncountably, even if the word would normally be countable:

> Write your name in pencil  (not in a pencil)
>   I came by bike (not by a bike)
>   Send it by return post (not a return post)

Similarly, when the method is "owl" you say "by return owl". And the original letter was delivered "by owl" too.

Answer (score -1):

In the HP world, Wizard mail is via *Owl Post*.  Thus, 30 years ago you might have said something like, "Drop the hotel keys in the **return mail**".  In this case, because they're wizards, substitute "mail" for "Owl".

That's because "*I want you to swear, **by return owl**, that you are not going to go walking with anyone else at night*" means that they are swearing on the trustworthiness of Owl Post.